# Rails: save multiple records to database at same time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I am creating an app where sellers (users) save a record every time they sell an item. This information is stored in a table called `items`. This table holds `user`, `items_sold` and `day`.

What I want to do now is:

1. Get all records for a specific day
2. Group these records by user
3. Sum `items_sold`
4. Create a new record for each user in a different table `reports` that holds `user`, the sum of `items_sold` and `day`

To make it more clear:

I want to go from...

[image]

to...

[image]

What I have so far is:

```
@consolidated_items = Item.all.group(:user).sum(:items_sold)
```

Which gives me:

```
{"dave"=>9, "steve"=>20}
```

However, I don't know what to do now. With my solution so far `day` is missing. Also I don't know how to save these data now to the `reports` table (I want something like a button saying "Create report" - once a user pushes it the records in reports will be created).

Answer (score 0):

The `day` is not present in your solution because you are not grouping by this field (you do it with `user`, so `user` becomes part of your key) and you are not performing any batch operation on it (you do it with `items_sold` because you `sum` them).

It seems you want to sum the amount of `items_sold` by `user` and `day`, so you have to use `.group([:user, :day])` instead.

In case you don't want to group by `day`, there is no deterministic way to retrieve the date because there could be more than one for the same user.

Once you have properly retrieved your data, you need to build an persist your associated report, that is:

```
Report.create { user: the_user_from_db, 
                items_sold: the_count_from_db, 
                day: the_day_from_db }
```

In addition, I would recommend storing the `user_id` in the `reports` table instead of the username itself.

The bulk record insertion is not supported by Activerecord but you can use gems like [BulkInsert](https://github.com/jamis/bulk_insert) to achieve this functionality

Comment: Ok thanks. However, I still don't know how to save multiple records at the same time: I want to save the reports for "steve" and "dave" at the same time with one action.